# WFS consumed in QGIS generates duplicate features

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs, duplication

**Problem:** When some of my layers are published by Geoserver 2.8.0 and added as WFS layer in QGIS 2.16.0 some of the data are duplicated. The duplicated data do not have geometry. I have observed this in two layers that I am serving but it is not consistent with all of them. However for those two layers the same does **NOT** apply when the data are imported in FME 2016 or ArcGIS 10.3.1 using the interoperability extension.

**Background:** The geoserver layers are held as 'views' in a PSQL 9.4 server which sits in Ubuntu 14.04. The views are generated using a statement of the following form:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW geoserver_view AS
(
SELECT 
column_1,
column_2,
column_3,
...,
geom 
FROM schema_name.table_name
)
```

I have also tried creating or replacing the views using the following form of view creation as suggested in the [Duplicate entries in table list when adding PostGIS layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185324/duplicate-entries-in-table-list-when-adding-postgis-layer-in-qgis) but I observed the same records duplication.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW schema_name.geoserver_view AS 
(
SELECT 
column_1,
column_2,
column_3,
...,
geom::Geometry(MultiPolygon, 27700),
FROM schema_name.table_name
)
```

I think that QGIS is probably the problematic software here since I have checked the data in PSQL and they are fine, and when importing the WFS in other software no record duplication is observed.

Any insights?

Comment: I am sorry for being impatient but it strikes me that it only happens in our system and hasn't happened to anyone else. Is this something that needs to be submitted in a developers' forum?

Comment: Is QGIS sending duplicate requests?

Comment: How would you know that?

Comment: Use Fiddler to and proxy the requests sent by QGIS (network settings) to see what http requests are being generated

Answer (score 1):

QGIS WFS-T in >= 2.16 has some serious issues: have a look to the WFS related issues on http://hub.qgis.org/issues/