# PostGIS table shows twice in QGIS Browser panel

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I've observed for a while that for many (but not all) of my tables, QGIS 3 (2.99) shows the same table name twice in the Browser Panel on the left, when I expand my PostGIS data source.

The first entry in the Browser view can be loaded into QGIS normally, but the second instance gives a `Coordinate Reference System Selector` dialogbox and once loaded shows no data at all.

*Does someone know why this happens and is it possible to not show the 2nd entry?*

Related question: [Duplicate entries in table list when adding PostGIS layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185324/) said that PostGIS tables are duplicated in Table list, but

> everything's fine in browser panel

Comment: How did the data came into the PostGIS DB? What is the table definition? As far as I see this happens when the geometry is defined as 'generic' in order to have various geometry types in one table.

Comment: Do you have srid set for your table?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it after adding the SRID during the creation of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  city_name character varying,
  geom geometry(Point, 4326))
```

Note, that each inserted geometry needs to have an SRID as well:

```
INSERT INTO cities (city_name, geom)
VALUES('New York', ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-73.935242, 40.730610)', 4326));
```